# Sharing one component within Angular 6 app that has multiple modules

Tags: angular, angular6

I'm splitting one large module to several smaller modules and have this issue:
1. Search component is used between multiple component. For now it's declared in app.module.ts. Later it will be moved to shared.module.ts.
2. Wrapper component uses search component. When I create simple wrapper.module.ts I get an error that app-search isn't known element. If i declare it in wrapper.module.ts, I will get an error that search component is declared in 2 different modules, which makes sense. 
Why search component is declared in app.module.ts but not visible by component that has a separate module? I can't declare search comp. inside wrapper.module.ts because it'll be used later by other components.
CLI restart doesn't help. 'app-search' is a correct selector name.

app.module.ts:

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { WrapperModule } from '../wrapper/wrapper.module';
import { SearchComponent } from '../search/search.component';

@NgModule({
 imports: [
  CommonModule,
  WrapperModule
 ],
 declarations: [
  AppComponent,
  SearchComponent
 ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Wrapper module:

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { WrapperComponent } from './wrapper.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
   CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [
   WrapperComponent
  ],
  exports: [
   WrapperComponent
  ],
 })
export class WrapperModule {}
```

Wrapper.component.html

```
<app-search></app-search>
```

Search component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-search',
  templateUrl: './search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search.component.scss'],
})
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a component across multiple modules, you'll need to create a "shared" module and add that component the shared module's `exports`. Then you add that shared module into your other modules `imports`

Every module is It's own ecosystem, with its own imports.
Once you turned **WrapperComponent** to **WrapperModule** it does not have access to AppModule imports anymore and has to have its own.

Answer (score 1):

The issue will be solved when you move the search component to the shared module (or shared feature module).

You cannot use it like a provider where providing it in root allows all units in and below the module to access it because it may require other components/etc from the module it's in. If being able to access components from a parent module were possible, things could get weird when modules are lazy loaded.

An alternative is to make a module just for a shared component or set of functionality (take a look at how the [Angular Material](https://github.com/angular/material2/tree/master/src/lib) team handles this). Creating specific modules that operate on their own instead of a generic "shared" module allows you to be more specific with what you want available where, only exporting components the module needs to expose (not all components need exported).

Comment: Thanks for linking that!